# Shader TextureLod parameter value?

Tags: opengl, glsl

What value does the LOD parameter take for [texturelod](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/textureLod.xhtml)? The spec I found doesn't mention it at all. Is it a percentage or an index value with a percent. If the later is the case, is there a way to get the number of mipmaps the texture has so that I would be able to use a percentage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The LOD parameter](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Lod_texture_access) specifies the mipmap level, rounded to the nearest whole number. Remember that OpenGL specifies mipmap levels, such that 0 is the largest, with increasing numbers going smaller.

However, the LOD specified here will *always* be relative to the [current `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` of the texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Mipmap_Range). So if you use `textureLod(..., 0)`, and the base level is set to mipmap 2, then you will select from mipmap level 2. You also cannot select mipmaps outside of the `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` range; the system will automatically clamp the specified parameter appropriately.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the texture has to be set up with one of the `GL_XXX_MIPMAP_YYY` filters for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` in `glTexParameteri()`. Otherwise GLSL will always use LOD 0 in `textureLod()`, regardless of the parameter, and not lose a peep about it.